# Castle Windsor Generic Type Registration

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, registration

I am new to castle windsor and dependency injection. I have a question about registration of generic types.

This is a similar example to my issue. (Just created in a small project to able to solve, but couldnt solve it)
     I have a web api project which has default ValuesController

```
      public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        IVehicleManager _service;          
        public ValuesController(IVehicleManager service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }
        .
        .

        // GET api/values/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return $"value {_service.GetVehicleInfo(id)};";
        }


    }
```

This as a dependency to IVehicleManager. I injected this dependency to my controller.

VehicleManager.cs class implements IVehicleManager interface. Also it has a dependency to a generic Vehicle type.

```
    public class VehicleManager : IVehicleManager
    {
        IVehicle<IInfo> _info;
        public VehicleManager(IVehicle<IInfo> info)
        {
            _info = info;
        }
        public string GetVehicleInfo(int id)
        {
            return _info.GetNameOfBrand(id);
        }
    }

    public interface IVehicleManager
    {
       string GetVehicleInfo(int id);
    }
```

Vehicle is a generic class which implements IInfo interface, also has dependencies to ICalculator and "brandName" field.

```
     public class Vehicle<T>:IVehicle<T> where T:IInfo
    {
        ICalculator _calculator;
        string _brandName;
        public Vehicle(string brandName, ICalculator calculator)
        {
            _brandName = brandName;
            _calculator = calculator;
        }

        public string GetNameOfBrand(int id)
        {

            return $"{_brandName} and {_calculator.GetAge(id)}" ;
        }
    }

    public interface IVehicle<T>
        where T:IInfo
    {
        string GetNameOfBrand(int id);

    }
```

ICalculator has different implementations and one of them is (code doesnt have any meaning)

```
    public class AgeCalculator : ICalculator
    {
        public long GetAge(int id)
        {
            return id;
        }
    }
      public interface ICalculator
    {
        long GetAge(int id);
    }
```

I have IInfo interface which is implemented by BaseInfo and ChildInfo classes as below:

```
     public class BaseInfo : IInfo
    {
        public string BrandName { get; set; }
    }
    public class ChildInfo2 : BaseInfo
    {
        public string TypeOfVehicle { get; set; }
    }
    public interface IInfo
    {
        string BrandName { get; set; }
    }
```

I register these components by Castle Windsor as below to my ServiceInstaller.cs

```
     public class ServiceInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
    {
        public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
            container.Register(Component.For<ICalculator>().ImplementedBy<AgeCalculator>().LifestylePerWebRequest());
            container.Register(Component.For<IInfo>().ImplementedBy<BaseInfo>().LifestylePerWebRequest(),
                Component.For<IInfo>().ImplementedBy<ChildInfo>().LifestylePerWebRequest(),
            Component.For(typeof(IVehicle<IInfo>)).ImplementedBy(typeof(Vehicle<IInfo>)).DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("brandName", "bmw")).DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent<IInfo,BaseInfo>())
            .LifestylePerWebRequest(),
        Component.For<IVehicleManager>().ImplementedBy<VehicleManager>().DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent<IInfo, ChildInfo>()).DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent<IVehicle<IInfo>, Vehicle<IInfo>>()).LifestylePerWebRequest());

        }
    }
```

When I try to run api/values/5 (HTTPGet) I got the error below.

```
 Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DependencyResolverException occurred
    HResult=0x80131500
    Message=Missing dependency.
    Component WebApplication1.Controllers.ValuesController has a dependency on                 
    BusinessLogic.IVehicleManager, which could not be resolved.
    Make sure the dependency is correctly registered in the container as a 
    service, or provided as inline argument    

    Inner Exception 1:
    HandlerException: Handler for BusinessLogic.IVehicleManager was not found.
```

If anyone can help me how to register these generic types?
Thank you

Comment: How is your `ServiceInstaller` class registered? Show your `Startup.cs` / `Global.asax`

Comment: Yes I did, the issue is related to generics, when i try to do with non-generic types it is working. I registered from Global.asax

Comment: What version of Windsor is this?